# Why can't I see the JS heap/documents/nodes/listeners/GPU memory section in my dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

Why can't I see the Js heap/documents/nodes/listeners/gpu memory section in my dev tools?

[image]

I am following this guide to fix memory leaks: https://betterprogramming.pub/javascript-memory-leaks-390957523a9e

[image]